# Convert string to only byte in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a problem, want to convert a decimal byte to a hexadecimal byte, pass it to string to be able to make the conversion more quickly but now my question is as follows. Know how can I convert a string to a byte the string

example:

NSString *var = @"0x21";

To

Byte cmd = 0x21;

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an instance of NSString to an instance of NSData with  -dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: or to a C array with -getCString:maxLength:encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding.

In both cases you have a pointer to an object resp. to a char[]. Putting that pointer into the Byte array, will convert the pointer and copy its value, but not the referenced data.

Additionally: In your example you try to save 0.4 (zero – period – four) and 0.5 (zero – period – 5) into a Byte[]. This will not do the job, you probably expect. It will convert the value to a value of type Byte (an integer type!) and store that value. Integer values greater than 255 will be converted, too.

Therefore you have to use a mutable data object and concat the binary representation of the different types individually.